# Cypress 400 xhr error when clicking on a button

Tags: cypress

I have a button which will redirect to the application upon clicking it.

But when my automation script runs, it is always throwing POST 400 error.

I tried manually in my browser, and there is no error in the network tab. And also if you use Cypress to open the browser and load the application, there is no error.

I saw a similar one [here][1] but does not seem to solve my issue.

Test.js file :

```
describe ('Test', function()
{

 it('Login', function(){

 cy.url().should('include', '<url goes here>');
 cy.wait(3000)
 cy.get('h1').should('have.text', "WELCOME")  

 cy.get('button').contains("submit").click() ////executed till here. POST 400 error after this

 })
}
)
```

HTML code :

```
<button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiButton-root MuiButton-contained" tabindex="0" type="button">
  <span class="MuiButton-label"> submit</span>
```

Error after running automation code :

```
(xhr) POST 400 : <api-url> 
This is the response on the network tab => Failed to load response data : No resource with given identifier found.
```

Comment: Add the code you tried along with the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to add `failOnStatusCode:false,` into your cy.request?

You can read more here: [cypress documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/request)

Comment: I am still getting (xhr) POST 400 error. The response in network tab for that api call is showing *Failed to load response data : No resource with given identifier found.*